# Интеграция SQL с .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclr

Необходимо реализовать некоторый функционал обработки данных SQL сервера при помощи .NET.

По ключевым словам "Интеграция .NET и SQL" находятся, в первую очередь, описания "SQL CLR". Попробовал сие, и столкнулся с рядом серьезных проблем, которые не позволяют его использовать:

- Сложности в регистрации .NET сборок на SQL сервере. А именно: я использую сторонние библиотеки. Во время их регистрации указывается об необходимости регистрировать system.servicemodel. Если пытаюсь регистрировать system.servicemodel, необходима регистрация сборки system.servicemodel.internals, а этой сборки я не нахожу.
- Зависимость версии сервера от версии .NET: Sql сервер версии 2008 использует .NET до версии 3.5, соответсвенно сторонние сборки тоже должны быть скомпилированы в версиях не старше 3.5. Мною используемые библиотеки доступны только в версии 4.0. Таким образом отпадает возможность их использования в версиях SQL сервера до 2008. Для меня слишком критично.

Итак, меня интересуют другие доступные способы интерации .NET и SQL.

Во время проб SQLCRL возникла идея использовать WCF сервис из пользовательских SQL функций. Таким образом я бы мог всю "грязную" работу (и зависимости от сторонних библиотек) переложить на сторону сервиса, а в контракте использовать лишь простые структуры данных. Сервис должен тогда работать локально и испльзовать самое быстрое бинарное соединение (возможно pipe).

Как вам такая идея? Может быть существуют другие способы, попроще?

Спасибо за советы.

Comment: Проще говоря, вам нужно из под .NET работать с БД, верно?

Comment: Не совсем. Мне нужно из БД работать с .NET

Comment: Что вы под этим подразумеваете?

Comment: Нужно расширить возможности обработки данных на SQL сервере при помощи .нет, т.к. возможностей T-SQL не хвататет. Вот одна из ранних статей по одному из возможных вариантов на рсдн: https://rsdn.ru/article/db/yukondotnet.xml

Comment: Не могли бы вы рассказать, как имено вы хотите расширить возможности обработки данных?

Comment: конвертировать некоторые документы, сохраненные в бд, в pdf

Comment: Документы представлены в виде байтстрима или вы какие то объекты хотите преобразовывать в pdf документы?

Comment: Имеет ли это какое-то значение? Я не могу вдаваться в подробности. Задача, думаю, описана ясно.

Answer (score 3):

Идея использовать SQLCLR для описанного сценария может казаться привлекательной, но имеет свои минусы, и для описанной задачи есть другие решения.

**Основные минусы SQLCLR**

Основной минус это maintainability проекта, использующего подобную интеграцию, и здесь Вы уже столкнулись с некоторыми трудностями.

**Плюс SQLCLR**

Плюс SQLCLR может быть в том, можно избежать многочисленных внешних запросов к SQL для представления данных из реляционных таблиц в структурированном виде для компоненты обработки.

**Способ проще**

Это собственно основной способ интеграции .NET и SQL, где есть клиент .NET, и сервер SQL, а не наоборот, как в случае SQLCLR. Сбор структурированных данных из реляционных таблиц в этом случае можно выполнить с помощью `for xml` с подзапросами.

Заметьте, что в случае вызова внешней компоненты обработки изнутри SQL, и записи полученного ответа в таблицу, данные передаются два раза: туда - сериализованных документ, обратно - бинарные данные PDF.

В случае вызова SQL для получения структурированных данных, и отправки для сохранения обратно - точно такие же по смыслу данные, в тех же самых направлениях. То есть, в терминах обмена сообщениями в межпроцессном взаимодействии, будет следующее:

```
(Запрос из SQL в .NET):  SQL -> Cтруктура    -> NET (1)
(Ответ  из .NET в SQL):  NET -> PDF          -> SQL (2)

Либо:
(Запрос из .NET в SQL):  NET -> id документа -> SQL (дешево)
(Ответ  из SQL в .NET):  SQL -> Cтруктура    -> NET (1)
(Запрос из .NET в SQL):  NET -> PDF          -> SQL (2)
(ОК от SQL)           :  SQL -> OK           -> NET (дешево)
```

Видим, что основной обмен сообщениями (1, 2) остается таким же в обоих случаях.

**Компромисс**

Есть и компромиссный вариант, где SQLCLR все же будет использоваться, но только в ограниченном варианте - только для сериализации контракта. `for xml` может оказаться неудобным по каким то причинам, например - если уже есть оговоренный формат сериализации, который удобнее реализовать средствами .NET.

Этот вариант поможет пользоваться удобством программирования на .NET, возможно - повторно использовать код сериализации контракта, а так же поможет избежать зависимости от компонент, которые накладывают свои технологические ограничения.

**Молоток побольше**

Судя по комментариям, для автора важно, чтобы SQL Server  стал точкой интеграции нескольких систем, поэтому стоит посмотреть в сторону очередей Server Broker.

Service Broker в частности поддерживает активацию внешних процессов.

Типовые варианты использования компонента Service Broker 
https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms166071(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Есть ограничение - клиенты не только лишь .NET-клиенты. Инициатор обработки данных - SQL (например тригер, или по расписанию, или запрос клиента (Select) - не важно). Со всеми вытекющими.

Comment: Напрашивается еще один вариант - вызов .NET приложения через xp_cmdshell.

Но и здесь получаем ряд проблем:
- Передача данных для обработки в консольное приложение (да, xml структура здесь поможет); Проблема возврата данных в SQL сервер.
- (или) передача идентификаторов данных (ключей записей) и данных подключения к базе. Программа сама извлекает данные, их обрабатывает и пишет результат. Неудобно работать с результом, если он должен быть представлен как результат запроса, без предварительного сохранения.

Comment: PS. Пример с PDF является лишь частью того что хотелось бы рализовать. Есть и другие задачи, которые я хочу переложить на плечи SQL. Поэтому я не хочу ограничиваться частным случаем с PDF. Нужна интеграция SQL с .NET с возможностью обработки данных SQL, использования сторонних библиотек, поддержки всех версий SQL хотя бы с версии 2008.

Comment: @SergejLoos инициатором должен быть sql - ок, но требуется ли синхронная обработка? Если нет - то достаточно просто организовать очередь заданий в виде таблицы, с закидыванием новых заданий в sql, и пулингом на наличие новых заданий со стороны отдельного приложения .net.

Comment: @PashaPash. Нужна синхронная обработка.

Answer (score 1):

После некоторых экспериментов хотел бы поделиться своим опытом.

Я продолжил развивать идею обработки данных при помощи локального сервиса WCF. Сделал небольшое тестовое приложение.
Сразу скажу, что использовать WCF в смысле "Service Reference" (соврменный .NET клиент для WCF служб) не получилось: основные проблемы возникли при регистрации различных сборок, которые не входят в число поддерживаемых. Кроме того, необходимо четко определять и разделять версии сборок .NET и SQL Servera, битность системы, битность сервера. Кроме того смешанные сборки (которые содержат чистый управляемый код и неуправляемый) не могут быть зарегестрированы на сервере. Долго бился - очень сложно.

Зато испльзовать WCF как "Web Refernece" (устаревший, но еще доступный вариант, который основывается на .NET 2.0) вполне получилось.
В этом случае привязка "NamedPipes", как я хотел, недоступна - можно задействовать лишь HttpBasic. Но тем не менее - работает! Кроме того, не понадобилось регистрировать какие-то дополнительные сборки .NET. Но потребовалось создание дополнительной сборки сериализации для моей сборки (в интрене легко нагуглить, что это, как и почему) - содержит инструкции относительно сериализции, которые в нормальной обстановке генерируются налету, но в ограниченной SQL.NET среде должны быть представленны явно. Ну и, ясно, что никаких app.config SQL Server не понимет, поэтому вся конфигурация у меня прописана жестко в коде (для хранения настроек можно было бы использовать сам SQL server). Также были проблемы при передачи на WCF сервис больших байтовых массивов - WebReference-Клиент не имеет настроек типа MaxMessageSize. Такое решил с помощью чанкинга - передачи данных небольшими порциями.

SQL Service Database Project содан для целевой платформы 3.5, без проблем выполняется и на SQL Server 2008 R2 и на SQL Server 2012.

Comment: А что мешало обновить .NET до актуальной версии?

Comment: @Bezarius. Для каких целей? SQL Server 2008 работает с clr 2 версии (.NET framework 3.5 тоже работает на 2-ом clr); SQL Server 2012 уже на четвертом. Четвертый обратно-совместим со вторым, наоборот - нет. Ясно, что легче и проще использовать рантайм 2 версии.

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще одно решение, которое я бы хотел в кратце изложить и по-возможности узнать мнение специалистов, т.к. я не знаком в достаточной мере с используемой технологией: Com+.

По сути, решение не отличается от того, которое использеут локальную Web-службу. Только ей на смену приходит COM+ сервис. COM+ сервис пишется на .NET, использует необходимые сторонние библиотеки, наружу торчит интерфейс, оперирующий простыми типами.

```
[JustInTimeActivation]
public class Class1 : ServicedComponent, Interface1
{
    [AutoComplete]
    public byte[] MyMethodName(byte[] inputData, string ext ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

SqlCLR-функция обращаятся к COM+ службе при помощи рефликции:

```
Type customType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ClassLibraryCom1.Class1"); 
Object customObj = Activator.CreateInstance(customType);
Object objValue = customType.InvokeMember("MyMethodName", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, customObj, new Object[] { param1, param2 } );
```

Данный подход я испробовал на небольшом теством проекте - выполнение ощутимо быстрее чем веб-сервис, хоть и рефлексия (насколько быстрее - пока неясно, нужно замерять). Расход памяти - примерно такой же.

Comment: В ответах не принято задавать дополнительные вопросы, лучше задать отдельный вопрос, или уточнить изначальный.

Comment: Это не вопрос, этот ответ. Решение работает. Просто хочется коментариев посвященных. Кстаи, убрал из ответа вопросительную часть